# CME isn't loading in Firefox (TypeError: $extUtils.isCurrentUserInGroup is not a function)

Tags: web8

[image: The error in my browser console]

My CME is not loading correctly in Firefox, when I followed these steps:

1. Clear all history/cache and close Firefox.
   [image: Image showing how the history and cache is cleared]
2. Open the Content Manager Explorer (SDL Web 8)
3. The CME fails to load and just shows a blank screen (see screenshot below)
   [image: Image showing the broken CME]

It *does* load properly if I press F5 again afterwards.

What can I do to fix this? Are there any additional settings to configure in Firefox?

Comment: Check the console, are there any errors?

Comment: no error in console. please refer attached console screen shot.

Comment: I've edited this question too, so it is more readable. Including formatting it correctly. Please make a little more effort to format, spell-check, and phrase your question in a way that makes it easy to read and answer. Thanks!

Comment: So the issue is related to an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final I found the issue in tridion namespace and updated the new namespace, its working fine now.

OLD Namespace:
Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands)

NEW Namespace:SDL.Web.UI.Editors.CME.CommandSets.All)

Comment: In which file did you change it?

Comment: i updated in editor.config file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this error might come from a GUI extension. Since it apparently only occurs when you clear your cache in Firefox, it seems like a classic timing issue (the script tries to access stuff before it is available).

If it isn't obvious which extension causes this, I would start disabling them one by one until you cannot reproduce it anymore. Then report the issue to the author of the extension.

(If I'm wrong and this is actually not in an extension, simply report the issue to SDL Customer Support instead)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is the extension (or some variant of) noted in [snipt](https://snipt.net/Puntero/check-if-a-user-is-belongs-a-group/):

Are you calling this function before some dependency such as the user (see `var settings = this.getUserSettings();` ) or before the function itself is even available?

I would locate where you are calling this (1) and then do some standard GUI debugging to provide us with more details to help get to the root cause.

(1) maybe switch compacting of JS off and search through for reference to this function and deduce which extension is trying to use it